# Elegant way to transform arrays in C#?

Tags: c#, linq

Is there a nice LINQ (or other) method of creating a new array by performing a transformation on each element of an existing array?

E.g. an alternative to:

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
foreach(string digit in stringArray)
{
  numbers.Add(Convert.ToInt32(digit));
}
return numbers.ToArray();
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
return stringArray.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 9):

Something like this?

```
int[] numbers = stringArray.Select(s => Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToArray();
```

Or, with query syntax:

```
int[] numbers = (from s in stringArray
                 select Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 5):

Yep! LINQ is perfectly suited to this sort of thing. Here's an example using [query syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397676.aspx):

```
return (from s in stringArray 
        select Convert.ToInt32(s)).ToArray();
```

BFree's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4138454/elegant-way-to-transform-arrays-in-c/4138486#4138486) is the method syntax equivalent. Here's an [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397947.aspx) on the difference between the two.